# How can I get the current time in particular format, for a particular zone?

Tags: java, jodatime

I want to get the current DateTime in a zone of my choice and in a particular format (eg HH-MM-SS, MM-DD-YY, MoMo-DD-YY-HH-MM-SS etc). 
How can I do this, using JodaTime?

Comment: What have you tried? You can easily get the current time in a specific zone using the `DateTime` constructor, and you can format it to a specific format using `DateTimeFormat`. Where are you stuck?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I can make a DateTime (DT) with zone. Not sure which is better - DateTimeZone.forID(XXXX) or DateTime(TheZone). After this step, how do I convert the DT i obtained into a particular format ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you've already seen the user guide (which includes sections on [time zones](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#TimeZones) and [formatting](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#Formatters)), it's not really clear where your confusion is. Some sample code to get you going:

```
DateTimeZone zone = DateTimeZone.forID("Europe/London");
DateTime currentTimeInLondon = new DateTime(zone);
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("HH:mm:ss, MM-dd-yyyy");
String text = formatter.print(currentTimeInLondon); // e.g. 08:24:54, 09-26-2012
```

It would be worth you taking some time to analyze *why* you couldn't get to this code yourself, given the information in the user guide. Being able to work out how to use APIs is a very important skill as a software engineer - you mustn't expect to be spoonfed code all the time.

Comment: Yes, I saw it. It also works with YourDateTime.toString("PutALegalFormatHere");

Comment: @davidblaine: Yes, but that's not generally as clean - in particular, you can usually create a `DateTimeFormat` *once* and reuse it throughout your application lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

this may help you.
http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get time according to particular zone with format.

```
    Locale locale = Locale.FRENCH;

    // Format with a custom format
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E, dd MMM yyyy", locale);
    String s = formatter.format(new Date());
    // mar., 29 sept. 2012

    // Format with a default format
    s = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM, locale).format(new Date());
    // 29 sept. 2012
```

Comment: check out link for joda time.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106143/work-around-for-a-joda-time-bug-in-periodformat